using purrr instead of for loop and updating object recursively
Given a data frame such as the following:
dat <- data.frame(
     plotType = c("RP", "FP"),
     turbType = c("3;8", "5;7"),
     turbSize = c(2.4, "3.6;4.2"),
     estimate = c(0.1, 0.5)
   )

I need to call tidyr::separate_longer_delim recursively for each column in:
strat <- c('turbType', 'turbSize')

This for loop achieves my goal but I was wondering if there was a purrr solution? Maybe with reduce()?
for(i in seq(length(strat))) {
     dat <- tidyr::separate_longer_delim(dat, dplyr::all_of(strat[i]), delim = ";")
   }

Thank you.

1) Using Reduce
library(tidyr)

f <- function(x, y) separate_longer_delim(x, all_of(y), delim = ";")
Reduce(f, strat, init = dat)

2) or with purrr and f from above:
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

reduce(strat, f, .init = dat)



Does not work but both 2 and 3 do.


Hmm. Not sure why I thought it did.  Anyways Have removed it and re numbered the remaining ones as 1 and 2.

I would do it like this:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  separate_longer_delim(cols = c(turbType, turbSize), delim = ";") |>
  group_by(id) |>
  complete(turbType, turbSize) |>
  fill(plotType, estimate, .direction = "downup") |>
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#      id turbType turbSize plotType estimate
#   <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
# 1     1 3        2.4      RP            0.1
# 2     1 8        2.4      RP            0.1
# 3     2 5        3.6      FP            0.5
# 4     2 5        4.2      FP            0.5
# 5     2 7        3.6      FP            0.5
# 6     2 7        4.2      FP            0.5


hmm that seems to be on the right track however, it does not seem to be straightforward to adapt this code to be dynamic. I.e. I cant substitute strat for the columns that you named explicitly. Particularly, complete() complains when I pass in a vector of columns. Not sure why

Yeah, you'd need to use do.call or something similar for complete.
